# Best algorithm to compare massive data

Tags: algorithm, performance, python-3.x, string-comparison, bigdata

I have a big dataset as csv (334MB) which is looking like below.

```
month, output
1,"['23482394','4358309','098903284'....(total 2.5 million entries)]"
2,"['92438545','23482394',323103404'....(total 2.2 million entries)]"
3,"[...continue
```

Now, I need to compare what percent of the output in a month is overlapping with the one in previous month.

For example, when I compare month 1 and month 2, I'd like to get result like "Month 2 output has 90% overlap against month1", then "Month3 has 88% overap against Month2"

What's the best way to solve this problem by Python3?

Comment: Are the values in each particular month unique and always integers?

Comment: 334 MB is going to fit into the RAM of your average computer, so make sure not to overengineer this one. Please define this overlap: are these always integers? Does the '0' prefix matter? Are they unique? Is the order relevant?  Please add some of your code to show how would you compare two short, simple example strings in python. This will make things much easier.

Comment: @IvanSivak Values in each month are all unique and they are always integers.

Comment: If values are unique - what do you mean by "overlap" ?

Comment: @MBo  I mean there is no overlap within a list of a month. So, the value is unique in that sense. There is a overlap when you compare values of month1 and month2 for example.

Comment: @K.K. OK. It's worth to add this info into the question to make it more clear

Comment: Theoretically you can insert the contents of one list into a hashtable and thus get linear time complexity; in reality memory limits and collisions may become issues. The most reliable way is to sort one array and use binary search, or even sort both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use set intersection method to extract common elements b/w two arrays or lists. The complexity of set intersection is O(min(len(a), len(b)).

```
# generate random numpy array with unique elements
import numpy as np

month1 = np.random.choice(range(10**5, 10**7), size=25*10**5, replace=False)
month2 = np.random.choice(range(10**5, 10**7), size=22*10**5, replace=False)
month3 = np.random.choice(range(10**5, 10**7), size=21*10**5, replace=False)

print('Month 1, 2, and 3 contains {}, {}, and {} elements respectively'.format(len(month1), len(month2), len(month3)))

Month 1, 2, and 3 contains 2500000, 2200000, and 2100000 elements respectively

# Compare month arrays for overlap

import time

startTime = time.time()
union_m1m2 = set(month1).intersection(month2) 
union_m2m3 = set(month2).intersection(month3)

print('Percent of elements in both month 1 & 2: {}%'.format(round(100*len(union_m1m2)/len(month2),2)))
print('Percent of elements in both month 2 & 3: {}%'.format(round(100*len(union_m2m3)/len(month3),2)))

print('Process time:{:.2f}s'.format(time.time()-startTime))

Percent of elements in both month 1 & 2: 25.3%
Percent of elements in both month 2 & 3: 22.24%
Process time:2.46s
```

You may have better success on the overlap between month entries with actual data.

Comment: hi, is there any reason to use np.random.choice instead of random.sample? thanks.